# How to make folder , file using keyboard shortcut? For Windows 8

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

How to make folder/file using keyboard shortcut ? I am beginner user for that case do not know this shortcut.

Comment: folder - Ctrl+Shift+N

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For create New Folder Press : `Ctrl+Shift+n` and making text file : Click your mouse / Touch pad `right button` then press `w` and `t`

Comment: thank you Imran Khan problem solve .

Comment: Follow this link : http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic